# How to auto detect IP from running TcpListener on local network

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I've seen some applications auto detecting the TcpListener's IP on local network and connecting to it, From what I know local network IPs are different on each router, For example, In my current router my IP Is:

```
192.168.1.100
```

But in the last router that I had It used to be this:

```
192.168.1.2
```

How Is that possible to detect a running TcpListener of specified port from a local network?

Comment: your question is a little bit ambiguous. Do you want to get the local ip address of the machine running the TcpListener ?

Comment: @Jalal225 Yes, I'm looking to detect it from another device/ip in same local network.

Comment: you can't knows an ip address of another machine unless it tells you or by connecting to it (which will need an `IPEndPoint` to connect to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your server so that it also has a `UdpClient` (or similar) configured to receive broadcasts on a specific port. Then clients can broadcast a message on the LAN, which the server can respond to by including its TCP listening address. Then the client can use this address to actually connect the TCP connection.

This should always work within a LAN subnet. Depending on your LAN configuration, you might be able to get the broadcasts routed to other subnets within the LAN.

Another possible approach (depending on your LAN hardware) would be to use UPnP to set up port-forwarding on your router. Then you'd just always connect to the router, which would know which computer in the LAN actually should get the connection request.